# doctrine:mapping:import from existing oracle database not possible

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using an oracle db 12c with a table "data.account", "data.users" and "data.service".
I've created a separate user "api" with "select" permissions on these tables.

Then i've created a new symfony flex skeleton and added further requirements:

```
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.4",
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^6.0",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/cache": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/security-core": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*",
    "ext-json": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/browser-kit": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.13",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.3",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
  },
```

After this was the perfect time to test if the db connection is working:

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM data.ACCOUNT FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY"
```

Great this returns the expected result. Now i should be able to import these tables and generate entities. So i followed this [help-page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

So i tried:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity -vvv
Database does not have any mapping information.
```

Dammit. I've also tried:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml "App\Entity" --from-database --force                                                                                                                     
 [OK] No Metadata Classes to process.
```

My doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    charset: UTF8
    logging: "%kernel.debug%"
    profiling: "%kernel.debug%"
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
      App:
        is_bundle: false
        type: annotation
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
        prefix: 'App\Entity'
        alias: App
```

.env:

```
DATABASE_URL=oci8://user:pass@host:1522/dev
```

I've retried after deleting the cache with "php bin/console c:c" and even deleted the whole folder, but still its not working.

Thanks to @emix, we've narrowed the problem. After clearing the logs and retry i can see the following:

```
[2019-08-26 11:23:35] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT * FROM sys.user_tables [] []
```

So now i know that doctrine is trying to locate the currently owned tables from the user. But the data.ACCOUNT table lies in another schema and the table was granted "select". This table is not owned by this user.

So how can i tell doctrine to look into another schema for the granted tables?

Comment: And how does your DSN look like (dbal url)? Ommit the password pls ;)

Comment: @emix i've added the url in the description

Comment: `dev` is the database name?

Comment: @emix yes thats the name

Comment: I don't think "select" permissions are sufficient. Doctrine needs to be able to list all the tables and their details in order to create entities?

Comment: @emix I've tried to grant all rights on the specific table. But yeah could be that doctrine tries to get a table list through a specific Query and cannot access this. An idea how i could find this?

Comment: Not sure, I'd personally run a debug session using xdebug to find out why the table list and its details aren't picked up.

Comment: @emix That was a great idea! Thanks. Now i know that doctrine looks into sys.user_tables . But this is only the table for its own tables, not the tables that where granted to this user. An idea how to solve this?

Comment: OK doctrine uses for OraclePlatform.php:445 the function getListTablesSQL. It will only inspect the currently owned tables, not thos granted. I would have to duplicate the database_url with another user. This is contra productive for security reasons. 

Therefore i tried to create the entities manually with the makerbundle "make:entity" this works if i specify the schema:
 * @ORM\Table(name="data.account")

Comment: Is it so hard to create couple of entities by hand? ;)

Comment: @emix couple are ok, but dozen not, but will have to. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is Oracle likes to name tables and columns in upper case. So if you have a table in lower case Oracle will quote it and en ENtity with the name "entity".php is quite difficult!